# Finding example SMTP responses

Tags: smtp, email-server

I am writing a script to extract stats from mail logs. With some SMTP servers, extracting the SMTP error code can be difficult, and even with the error code, the associated text can contain useful data. To that end I am looking for examples of SMTP responses, but everything I find in google is just a regurgitation of the standard *meaning* of the 3 digit SMTP code.

Are there any lists of real SMTP responses (attributed to specific MTAs) published on the internet?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that  the standard does not supply a conclusive list of SMTP response codes and explicitly allows for variation :

> [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2):
> ... An **SMTP reply consists of a three digit number** (transmitted as three
> numeric characters) **followed by some text** unless specified otherwise
> in this document.
> The number is for use by automata to determine
> what state to enter next;
> the text is for the human user.

> The three
> digits contain enough encoded information that the SMTP client need
> not examine the text and may either discard it or pass it on to the
> user, as appropriate.  Exceptions are as noted elsewhere in this
> document.  In particular, the 220, 221, 251, 421, and 551 reply codes
> are associated with message text that must be parsed and interpreted
> by machines.  ***In the general case, the text may be receiver dependent
> and context dependent, so there are likely to be varying texts for
> each reply code.***

> ...

Where you can roughly interpret that *"the text is for the human user"* and  *"receiver dependent
and context dependent"* means that a developer is almost completely free to have their application return whatever text they feel is useful/appropriate  and that such text may for instance contain the email addresses of recipients and senders and server/domain names. The later is something most people won't publish publicly online.

> An SMTP client MUST determine its actions only by the reply code, not
> by the text
> ...

> The list of codes that appears below MUST NOT be construed as
> permanent.  While the addition of new codes should be a rare and
> significant activity, with supplemental information in the textual
> part of the response being preferred, new codes may be added as the
> result of new Standards or Standards-Track specifications.
> Consequently, a sender-SMTP MUST be prepared to handle codes not
> specified in this document and MUST do so by interpreting the first
> digit only.

Your script must essentially do the same, simply extract the 3 digit SMTP reply code from the particular log format your MTA generates and proceed from there.